# Ignore missing values when mapping column values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping

I have a column called **subgroup** which has values separated by comma. I have a dictionary with keys and values. I have scheduled a script to run automatically. But if the values in **subgroup** is not present in dictionary, the function will crash and stop. How can I ignore the values of **subgroup* if it not present in my dictionary?

[image]

here the column subgroup has values A,B,C,D,E but dictionary has key, values of A,B,C. I want to ignore D,E without throwing an error. How can I do this?
Below is the code I have written

```
mapping_dict = df.set_index('KEY')['VALUES'].to_dict()
df2_values = [v.split(',') for v in df_2['subgroup']]
df_2['subgroup'] = pd.Series([','.join([mapping_dict[v] for v in values]) for values in df2_values])
```

how can I update this code to avoid missing values??

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
df_2['subgroup'] = pd.Series([','.join([mapping_dict[v] for v in values]) for values in df2_values if values in mapping_dict])
```

Thus, it will only use the values from df2_values that exist in mapping_dict